# Styling colorchooser and filedialog in Tkinter to make it consistent with rest of the application

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I change the Style of colorchooser (askcolor) or filedialog (askopenfilename) to make it consistent with the rest of the application which uses ttk widgets and styles. I do not want to create these dialog boxes from scratch. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: tkinter will request these dialog boxes from your operating system. Tkinter dosent provide a way to change them, maybe your os does.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.